# PHP hide fatal error message and redirect

Tags: php, error-handling

If the following code returns a fatal error, I get a message on the page I don't want users to see. I want to hide the fatal error message and redirect the user to another page:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

To hide the error message, I just added:

```
error_reporting(E_NONE);
```

But how do I catch and redirect a fatal error like this?

Comment: `if(!$jinput){ header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/");}`

Comment: How about writing code that does not throw a fatal error?

Comment: @zerkms Because I know that something is happening when a fatal error is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicaly, you can't "catch" fatal errors because they stop program execution. But there is one method to handle them. Register your own shutdown handler and check if last error was fatal.

```
<?php
function shutdownHandler()
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error['type'] == E_ERROR) {
        your code goes here;
    }
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdownHandler');
```

Demo: https://eval.in/137869

Comment: Warning: register_shutdown_function() [function.register-shutdown-function]: Invalid shutdown callback 'shutdownHandler' passed in

Answer (score 9):

### Hiding errors from users

It's a very common misconception, people often confuse `error_reporting` with **`display_errors`** setting. You need the latter.

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

is what actually hides errors from site visitors. While `error_reporting` **must** always remain at `E_ALL`.

### Redirecting in case of error

This idea violates the most basic regulation of HTTP protocol. A page where irrecoverable error occurs, MUST return a 5xx status code, not 3xx. Therefore you should never do any redirect. A 5xx status code must be returned (i.e. 500) and anything you want to show on this page must be shown  right in place, without redirects.

### Catching the fatal error

Given the error is irrecoverable, and all you can do is just show the error page, what you really need here is a **site-wide error handler.** A code that would catch the error and do everything described above: return 500 HTTP status code, display some generic error page and also, which is very important, **log** the error message for the future inspection. In order to create such a handler you will need three functions, set_error_handler(), set_exception_handler() and register_shutdown_function(). You can see a simplified example of the code that uses all three functions in my article on [PHP error reporting](https://www.phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).